# Change Contact fields order in Mautic

Tags: crm, mautic

Even though I change the fields (custom or not) order in the Custom Fields screen in Mautic, that order doesn't reflect in the Contacts screen.

How can I customize the order and position of fields in the Contacts screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't find a solution ready for this need I decided to customize the leads form myself. After taking a look at the code I noticed it's really easy to change and maintain.

The solution was to order/position the fields directly on the view: **app/bundles/LeadBundle/Views/Lead/form.html.php**.